# Change font color of ion-title in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Hey I make a todo list app in ionic2, I have a sidebar list.
In list.html I have the following code:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <a menu-toggle>
    <icon menu></icon>
  </a>
  <ion-title class="listTitle">My First List</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

I'm trying to change the color of "My First List" to white with the css. 
but it's not working.
Also I defined a background color for the title, but it overrides the menu icon. Why is that?

The css:

```
.listTitle
{
    background-color : #58B43F;
    color : #ffffff !important;
    box-shadow : 0px 6px 10px #888888;
}
```

My expected result is that the navbar will be in green color with white title and white menu icon. How should I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ionic 2 uses keywords to reference SASS variables from the `app.variables.scss` file, which can be added as attributes directly to tags. Using this we can change `primary` and `secondary` to green and white:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #58B43F,
  secondary:  #fff,
  ...
);
```

For some reason it didn't work when I tried to apply the `secondary` colour attribute to the `ion-title` tag, but a nested text tag works fine (e.g. `<p>`).

So, below is how these colour aliases are used to style `ion-navbar` (note specifically where `primary` and `secondary` aliases are placed within the tag declarations):

```
<ion-navbar primary *navbar>
  <a menu-toggle>
    <icon menu></icon>
  </a>
  <ion-title>
    <p secondary>My First List</p>
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

**EDIT: Other customisations**

To adjust the navbar height, add these to `app.variables.scss`:

```
$toolbar-ios-height: 8rem; // ios
$toolbar-md-height: 8rem;  // android
```

To use a new font-family, override the `ion-navbar` style:

```
ion-navbar {
  font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.14em; 
}
```